# jeditable in an ASP.NET web form

Tags: c#, jeditable, webforms

Can someone explain to me how you would use jeditable with an ASP.NET web form (and C# codebehind). I've got a bit of experience with web forms but not very complicated stuff, and haven't used much jquery before, and this is just puzzling me. I understand how to put it in and attach it to the element you want to be editable, it's what jeditable does when you submit the text field that I don't get. How do you handle that in the webform in order to save the changed text? Hope someone understands my issue... Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to handle the POST that jEditable sends.  I went with a very simple one.  I made a new .aspx file and pointed jEditable to that.  In there, you can access the form's POSTed fields with this.Request.Form["..."] to do whatever you intend to do.  Here's a snippet:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    this.Response.Clear();
    this.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    this.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
    this.Response.StatusCode = 200;

    try
    {
        var postId = this.Request.Form["id"];
        var value = this.Request.Form["value"];

        this.Response.Write(value);

        switch (postId)
        {
            case "id1":
                // write 'value' to DB or whatever
                break;
            case "id2":
                // write 'value' to DB or whatever
                break;
            default:
                this.Response.StatusCode = 501; // Not Implemented
        }

        this.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you tell me, is there any way we can use it to same page where i want to edit the text, using some function. I don't to save text in database but want to reflect edited text on the same page.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: I don't quite follow your question, but you should probably just open up a whole new question about that and elaborate on what you're trying to do.